# Using Abbot to test Netbeans project GUI

Tags: java, user-interface, testing, netbeans

I'm trying to use Abbot to produce a test script for my GUI in netbeans, but I don't know why it keeps displaying error with my Main class's main() method (ClassNotFoundException).

All I'm doing is in this screenshot:

https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Untitled.png?w=820d5f56

And the error is here:

https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Untitled2.png?w=04db4e64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure two things:

1. Your **classpath** points to the right .jar file that is produced when you build your project .i.e in `dist/` folder.
2. Your **Target Class Name** has to include the package name i.e. `packagename.Main` instead of `Main`.

It should solve your problem.